# how can I send font font.ttf to other activity android

Tags: android, android-intent, fonts

I want to use font dynamically to other activity 
currently my font is set as

```
custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AbrilFatface-Regular.ttf");
font.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

I want to get this font to other activity dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Pass the path (`"fonts/AbrilFatface-Regular.ttf"`) via an `Intent` extra and have the other activity call `createFromAsset()`, or
- Maintain a process-level `Typeface` cache (e.g., `LRUCache` mapping a `String` font name to the `Typeface`), and pass the key to that cache entry via an `Intent` extra